# jquery button with cookies to remember menu setting after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

On my webpage visitors can sort the menu either by "relevance" or "date".
But when one chooses "relevance" and loads a new page, the selection goes back to "date".
As far as i found out, it is not possible to solve this problem without cookies!? So i uploaded "jquery-1.11.3.min.js" and "jquery.cookie.js" to my page.

Can I start to activate cookies for the button now?
How can I save cookies so that the option stays after the refresh?
Since 'date' is the default option I actually only need to save cookies when people select 'relevance'.
What would be the code to reach my goal?

Here is the code I use for my menu:

```js
/** 
 * Hier beginnt im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
 *
 * @param sortCriteria
 *   Name of the data-attribute for sorting.
 * @param itemsToSort
 *   A string selector for items for sorting.
 * @param container
 *   A container to put items.
 * @returns {Function}
 */
var sortByDataAttr = function (sortCriteria, itemsToSort, container) {
    return function () {

        // Grab all the items for sorting.
        var $collection = $(itemsToSort);

        // Sort them and append in to container.
        $collection.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(b).data(sortCriteria) - $(a).data(sortCriteria)
        }).appendTo($(container));
    };
},


/**
 * Remove class from all elements and apply to current.
 *
 * @param current
 *   HTML node to apply class.
 * @param activeClass
 *   Active-state string class.
 */
highlightActive = function (current, activeClass) {
    $('.' + activeClass).removeClass(activeClass);
    $(current).addClass(activeClass);
};

// Sort by 'data-date' at the start.
highlightActive('.btn-sort-date', 'btn-sort--active');
sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list');

$('.btn-sort-date').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list')();
});

$('.btn-sort-relevance').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();
});
// Hier endet im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
```

```html
<!-- Im JSFiddle startet der html Bereich hier -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside id="nav_menu-5" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-odd widget widget_nav_menu">
    <div class="menu-projects-container">
        <ul id="menu-projects" class="menu">

<div style="color:#A4A4A4" class="daterel"> 
<span class="btn btn-sort-date"><i>date</i></span>
<span>|</span>

                <span class="btn btn-sort-relevance"><i>relevance</i></span>
</div>

            <div class="projects">


<b>PROJECTS</b>

           
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                     <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="11" data-date="2015.6"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/brickstone-blues/">brickstone blues</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">video</span>
                         
                <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="7" data-date="2015.5"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/copypaste/">copy&#038;paste</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">installation</span>

                    <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="6" data-date="2015.4"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/zebral-fluids/">zebral fluids</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">gif</span>

                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="8" data-date="2015.3"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/fried-egg-variation/">fried egg variation</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">glass</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="8" data-date="2015.2"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/bearrr/">bearrr&#8230;</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">illustration</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="7" data-date="2015.1"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/glass-ribbon/">glass ribbon</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">glass</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="13" data-date="2014.5"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/emulsifier/">emulsifier</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">sculpture</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="9" data-date="2014.4"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/black-holes/">black holes</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">illustration</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="7" data-date="2014.3"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/this/">**** this!</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">concept</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="10" data-date="2014.2"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/heads/">heads</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">mask</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="5" data-date="2014.1"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/staining-glass/">staining glass</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">glass</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="11" data-date="2013.2"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/fishbird/">fish&#038;bird</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">flipbook</span>

                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-649" class="item" data-relevance="6" data-date="2013.1"><a href="http://thomasmedicus.at/faces/">faces</a>
<span style="color:#A4A4A4">sculpture</span>

                        </li>
            </div>
<!-- Im JSFiddle geht der html Bereich bis hier -->
```

thank you for your support!

Comment: You really need to clean up your `html`, `li` elements are not allowed as child of `div` and you have several `id` attributes with the same value. `id`'s are supposed to be unique.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i adapted the normal wordpress menu code for this and it works. if wordpress does it and if it works then it's fine for me.
are there any reasons why my code is problematic, such as incompatibility with some browsers etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cookies, you should add the following after `sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();` :

```
$.cookie('sortby', 'relevance', {expires:30});
```

And this at the beginning of you javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ('relevance' == $.cookie('sortby')) {
        sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();
    } else {
        sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list')();
    }
});
```

It'll look for a cookie with the name "sortby" and if the value is "relevance" it'll sort the list accordingly.

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work.

is my cookie function installed as soon as i upload "jquery-1.11.3.min.js" and "jquery.cookie.js" to my page and add  <script src="www.thomasmedicus.at/html/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="www.thomasmedicus.at/html/jquery.cookie.js"></script> to the head section?

or do i have to do sth else before i can use a coode that works with cookies?

Comment: I assumed you used [this script](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). You should download it in your wp-includes/js directory and include it like such : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://thomasmedicus.at/wp-includes/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> right after jquery in your head section.

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTML5 localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) should look like follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-sort-date').on("click", function(){
        localStorage.setItem("selected_item", "date");
    });

    $('.btn-sort-relevance').on("click", function(){
        localStorage.setItem("selected_item", "relevance");
    });

    var selected_item = localStorage.getItem("selected_item");

    if (selected_item) {
         sortByDataAttr(selected_item, '.item', '.list');
    }

});
```

Run it at the end of the page..

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you. can you please be a little bit more precise where to add the codes. where are the 'tabs' and where do i have to put the code if you say 'seperately'? i am not very well trained, thanks

Comment: Well, that was just an example.. I've updated with what you want, but without testing

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

**Add the cookie**

```
$('.btn-sort-date').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','date');
});

$('.btn-sort-relevance').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','relevance');
});
```

**And check the cookie on page load**

```
if (typeof $.cookie('sort') == 'undefined'){
    $.cookie('sort','date');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-date', 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list');
}
else{
    var sort=$.cookie('sort');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-'+sort, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr(sort, '.item', '.list');
}
```

**So your final code would be**

```
/** 
 * Hier beginnt im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
 *
 * @param sortCriteria
 *   Name of the data-attribute for sorting.
 * @param itemsToSort
 *   A string selector for items for sorting.
 * @param container
 *   A container to put items.
 * @returns {Function}
 */
var sortByDataAttr = function (sortCriteria, itemsToSort, container) {
    return function () {

        // Grab all the items for sorting.
        var $collection = $(itemsToSort);

        // Sort them and append in to container.
        $collection.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(b).data(sortCriteria) - $(a).data(sortCriteria)
        }).appendTo($(container));
    };
},


/**
 * Remove class from all elements and apply to current.
 *
 * @param current
 *   HTML node to apply class.
 * @param activeClass
 *   Active-state string class.
 */
highlightActive = function (current, activeClass) {
    $('.' + activeClass).removeClass(activeClass);
    $(current).addClass(activeClass);
};

if (typeof $.cookie('sort') === 'undefined'){
    $.cookie('sort','date');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-date', 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list');
}
else{
    var sort=$.cookie('sort');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-'+sort, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr(sort, '.item', '.list');
}

$('.btn-sort-date').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','date');
});

$('.btn-sort-relevance').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','relevance');
});

// Hier endet im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
```

**UPDATE:**

changed the way the functions were defined and it works as expected: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6g2oLtsz/5/)**

```
/** 
 * Hier beginnt im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
 *
 * @param sortCriteria
 *   Name of the data-attribute for sorting.
 * @param itemsToSort
 *   A string selector for items for sorting.
 * @param container
 *   A container to put items.
 * @returns {Function}
 */
function sortByDataAttr(sortCriteria, itemsToSort, container) {
        alert('inside');

        // Grab all the items for sorting.
        var $collection = $(itemsToSort);

        // Sort them and append in to container.
        $collection.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(b).data(sortCriteria) - $(a).data(sortCriteria)
        }).appendTo($(container));
};


/**
 * Remove class from all elements and apply to current.
 *
 * @param current
 *   HTML node to apply class.
 * @param activeClass
 *   Active-state string class.
 */
function highlightActive(current, activeClass) {
    $('.' + activeClass).removeClass(activeClass);
    $(current).addClass(activeClass);
};

if (typeof $.cookie('sort') === 'undefined'){
    alert($.cookie('sort'));
    $.cookie('sort','date');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-date', 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list');
}
else{
    alert($.cookie('sort'));
    var sort=$.cookie('sort');
    highlightActive('.btn-sort-'+sort, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr(sort, '.item', '.list');
}

$('.btn-sort-date').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('date', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','date');
});

$('.btn-sort-relevance').on('click', function () {
    highlightActive(this, 'btn-sort--active');
    sortByDataAttr('relevance', '.item', '.list')();
    $.cookie('sort','relevance');
});

// Hier endet im JSFiddle der JavaScript Bereich
```

Comment: thank you! adding the cookie worked but when i add the 'if, else' part, the whole sorting function doesnt work anymore. there has to be an error somewhere.

Comment: oh yeah, there was a mistyped cookie written cooke, fixed it, should work properly now ;)

Comment: still doesnt work. i put your code into a fiddle, the sorting doesnt work anymore...https://jsfiddle.net/6g2oLtsz/
one more error? :)

Comment: it didn't work in fiddle 'cause **jquery cookie plugin** wasn't loaded => https://jsfiddle.net/6g2oLtsz/1/

Comment: I don't know why but it seems like fiddle won't apply the changes after cookie check, but if you get an alert of the cookie on page load, you'll see that after clicking on the sorting buttons the cookie is set! =>https://jsfiddle.net/6g2oLtsz/2/ if you try this on a project I'm sure it'll work though

Comment: thanks so much amin for you effort, we're getting closer :)
the cookie seems to be set, yes. but also when i integrade the code into my webpage the same thing happens as in fiddle: when i refresh a windw pops up telling me either "date" or "relevance" which means the cookie is set in the right way. additionally strange: after the refresh the right button is "remembered" but it doesn't sort the list, so it cant be really 'active'.

Comment: i don't know if that works, but if the window wouldnt popup but instead trigger the value it is saying, then everything would be fine i guess.
i addet some CSS code, so it is easier to see which button is active:
https://jsfiddle.net/6g2oLtsz/3/
would be awsome if you kept helping me, were pretty close i think.

Comment: if you change the way you defined your functions it'll work, check out the update